# Oracle SQL correlated subquery: not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, oracle11g, subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper, correlated-subquery

I'm trying to count travels doctors went to and sum how much money tolls cost. I'm using ORACLE XE 11g and SQL Developer. I tried to do that with correlated subquery in SELECT but I'm getting this message:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 11
```

This is query I talked about:

```
SELECT person.name, person.surname, COUNT(DISTINCT travelID) AS numberoftravels, 
  (SELECT SUM(costs.cost) FROM costs
    JOIN travel ON costs.travelID = travel.travelID
    JOIN person ON travel.personID = person.personID
    JOIN staff ON travel.personID = staff.staffID
    WHERE stafftype = 'Doctor' AND costtype = 'tolls' and staff1.staffID = person.personID  
  ) AS tollscost

FROM travel JOIN person ON person.personID = travel.personID
  JOIN staff staff1 ON staff1.staffID = person.personID

WHERE stafftype = 'Doctor'
GROUP BY person.name, person.surname;
```

Counting worked just fine before I added subquery. Does anyone understand why I might be having this problem?

Comment: just move the subquery as a joined expression instead. It's also much more proper

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a GROUP BY column - personID

Comment: Thank you very much. In retrospect, this was a noob question, didn't know i had to order by anything else but attributes that are in SELECT except aggregates